# Python web scraping with Beauifulsoup to extract variables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just started with Beautifulsoup and would like to extract the variables `name`, `brand` and `price` from website http://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/category/_laptops-482723.html but do not get things working.

> ```
> <script>
>  var product1511322 = {"name":"ACER Aspire 3 A315-31-C3PK","id":"1511322","price":"399.00","brand":"ACER","ean":"4713883258289","dimension25":"InStock","dimension26":1.99,"dimension24":21.00,"category":"Computer","dimension9":"Laptops","dimension10":"Windows-laptops"};
> </script>
> ```

I tried...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/category/_laptops-482723.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')

script.find_all('var')
```

...but that doesn't work

Anyone suggestions how to extract all `name`, `brand` and `price` information to a list of dataframe?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in bs4, but `script.find_all('var')` sounds like you're looking for `<var>` tags under `script`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a suggestion what command to use to extract the three vars?

Comment: where is `name` , `brand` and `price` there on website .

Comment: If you know that the JavaScript is going to be static, you can pull out the JSON by regex, then parse the JSON. Otherwise you'll need to interpret the JavaScript with something like [PyExecJS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed you wanted a "list of dataframe". This gets a `list`, if you really want a "dataframe", that should be easy to adopt from this result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import ast  # abstract syntax tree to parse dictionary text

url = 'http://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/category/_laptops-482723.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
infos = []

for s in scripts:
    if 'var product' in s.text[0:12]:          # find the script of interest
        d = s.text.split(' = ')[1].strip(';')  # get the product information
        # parse information as dictionary text
        data = ast.literal_eval(d)

        infos.append(data)

# Here's the list
# print infos  #  [{'category': 'Computer', 'name': 'HP Pavilion X360 14-BA081ND', ... 'dimension9': 'Laptops', 'dimension10': 'Windows-laptops', 'brand': 'LENOVO'}]

# for i in infos:
#     print i['name']   # HP Pavilion X360 14-BA081ND
#     print i['brand']  # HP
#     print i['price']  # 629.00
```

There's probably a better way, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is certainly helpful.